# CoordinatorLayout apparently has FrameLayout Params

Tags: android, kotlin

While trying to set a BottomSheetBehavior with an appropriate callback to a CoordinatorLayout, I stumbled upon this. When getting the layout params of said CoordinatorLayout, I keep receiving FrameLayout params instead. This is the situation code-wise.

From BottomSheetDialogFragment implementation

```
override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog?, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<AmbientDialogBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(activity), R.layout.ambient_dialog, null, false)
    val params = activity?.findViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(R.id.homeCoordinatorLayout)?.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
    val behaviour = params.behavior
    if (behaviour != null && behaviour is BottomSheetBehavior) {
        behaviour.setBottomSheetCallback(behaviorCallback)
    }
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/homeCoordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightGray"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/addAmbientButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_dialog.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/ambientDialogTextLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ambientIdField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Identificativo Ambiente"
            android:text="@={vm.UIDLive}"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ambientNameField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Nome Ambiente"
            android:text="@={vm.nameLive}"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/confirmAmbientButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_white_24dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

The FrameLayout I am using in the main activity xml is used for another fragment, which I don't think has anything to do with the problem. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't confirmed this yet, but I believe the View you pass to `setContentView()` (or layout res that gets inflated) is added to a FrameLayout.

A View's LayoutParams are defined by its parent, not by it. So if you have a LinearLayout within a ConstraintLayout, calling `linearLayoutInstance.layoutParams` will return an instance of ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.

I do know, though, that `setContentView()` adds your layout to a ViewGroup, though. It may not be guaranteed that the root layout is a FrameLayout. You shouldn't cast `getParams()` on your root View, and rely instead on the default return of ViewGroup.LayoutParams.

EDIT:

You can see the list of possible layouts here: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/PhoneWindow.java#L2541.

`com.android.internal.R.content` is the ID of the root.

Looking at that list and the corresponding XML files, here's the list of potential root layout types:

- `R.layout.screen_swipe_dismiss` -> `com.android.internal.widget.SwipeDismissLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_title_icons` -> `FrameLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_progress` -> `FrameLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_custom_title` -> `FrameLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_action_bar` -> `FrameLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_title` -> `FrameLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_simple_overlay_action_mode` -> `FrameLayout`
- `R.layout.screen_simple` -> `FrameLayout`

You can even define your own with the `dialogCustomTitleDecorLayout` attribute (although this isn't available to applications). This is also only from the latest AOSP source code. It might not be the same on Samsung, Huawei, etc, or on other versions of Android.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain better this: "You shouldn't cast getParams() on your root View, and rely instead on the default return of ViewGroup.LayoutParams". I don't get what I am supposed to do. You are talking about ViewGroup, so how could I reference it on setupDialog? Anyway, thank you so much for answering in such a short time!

Comment: Sorry, wrong syntax and method. You have `layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`. Remove the `as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: But then, I can't access behavior, beacuse generic LayoutParams does not have it. Should I use the from() method from BottomSheetBehavior? But then again, I don't think it would work, since in the function it checks if layoutparams of the passed view is CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Behavior applies to the child Views, not the CoordinatorLayout itself.